# How to add an interaction term in JAGS between one categorical and one continuous variable?

Tags: bayesian, jags

I have mark recapture model in JAGS and I want to code a interaction between a categorical variable and a continuous variable.

`ngr` is the number of groups

`nind` is the number of individuals in my mark recapture model

`gr.sp[ind]` just searches in my database to which group belong individual ind

`ngr` is the number of groups

Som priors:

```
phi.precip ~ dnorm(0,0.01)

for(groups in 1:ngr) {
  phi.gr[groups] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
}
```

Here is a small part of the likelihood of my model:

```
...
for(ind in 1:nind) {
  for(yr in 1:nyear) {
    logit(phi[ind,yr]) <- e.phi[ind,yr]
    e.phi[ind,yr] <- 
      phi.gr[gr.sp[ind]] + # Categorical variable telling how much belonging to a certain group changes your fitness
      phi.precip * sum.rainfall[yr] + # Effect of rain on my individuals 

      phi.gr.precip * phi.gr[gr.sp[ind]] * sum.rainfall[yr]   # This is the interaction between the categorical and the continuous I'm trying to code. 

  }
...}
```

First, how do you define the prior for the `phi.gr.precip`? Should it be something resembling this:

```
for(groups in 1:ngr) {
  phi.gr.precip[groups] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
}
```

But then, I don't know how to implement it in the likelihood.

Second, how is `phi.gr.precip` supposed to be coded to include the interaction between the group an individual is in (`gr.sp[ind]`) and the climate (`sum.rainfall[yr]`, which represent the amount of rain in a year)?

Coding an interaction like like seems to require the same number of parameter in `phi.gr.precip` as there are in the categorical variable. But that would require me to loop inside the likelihood:

```
...
for(ind in 1:nind) {
  for(yr in 1:nyear) {
    logit(phi[ind,yr]) <- e.phi[ind,yr]
    e.phi[ind,yr] <- 
      phi.gr[gr.sp[ind]] +
      phi.precip * sum.rainfall[yr] +
  for(groups in 1:ngr) {
      phi.gr.precip[groups] * phi.gr[gr.sp[ind]] * sum.rainfall[yr]
   }
  }
...}
```

Which is not working when I run the model.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of prior looks reasonable.

Your likelihood is almost correct, but JAGS can't add a for-loop to a number. Instead, you need to move the for loop for groups up to wrap around the entire sum.

```
...
for(ind in 1:nind) {
  for(yr in 1:nyear) {
   for(groups in 1:ngr){  ### MOVE THE FOR-LOOP HERE
    logit(phi[ind,yr]) <- e.phi[ind,yr]
    e.phi[ind,yr] <- 
      phi.gr[gr.sp[ind]] +
      phi.precip * sum.rainfall[yr] + phi.gr.precip[groups] * phi.gr[gr.sp[ind]] * sum.rainfall[yr]
   }
  }
...}
```